# Combined Geolocation frameworks

Tags: javascript, geolocation, ip-geolocation

Basically, there are multiple Geolocation ways - GPS, WiFi positioning (skyhook), IP, cell triangulation.

Is there any framework/service which is able to use all of them?  (or at least first three)

Try most precise one, if fails - fall back to less precise one (GPS is off, indoors, user forbids cell detection etc.).
I've checked Google Gears - it uses only IP and GPS.

The best one would be Javascript framework (to be usable in web-applications) but any is fine for taking a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the HTML5 native method ?

```
getCurrentPosition(success_callback,error_callback)
```